# javascript asset not being found in gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, asset-pipeline

This should have been a no-brainer, but has me stumped.

For convenience, I took a bootstrap plugin ([bootstrap-combobox](https://github.com/taleinat/bootstrap-combobox)) and turned it into a gem, so I can version it properly and all.

My gem is [bootstrap-combobox-rails](https://github.com/constantorbit/bootstrap-combobox-rails).

It packages up fine, bundle installs fine, but when I try to reference the assets: The stylesheet works, although I have to do it like this in my `application.css.scss`:

```
@import "bootstrap-combobox.css";
```

(everything else is fine without the .css).

The javascript is not found, though.  No matter if I reference it as

```
//= require bootstrap-combobox.js
```

or

```
//= require bootstrap-combobox
```

I get:

```
$ rake assets:precompile
/Users/denishaskin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby /Users/denishaskin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@oneclick/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
couldn't find file 'bootstrap-combobox.js'
  (in /Users/denishaskin/clients/cs/1-click/oneclick/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:18)
```

Suggestions?  Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this.

It was one or both of these things, I don't recall exactly which did it.  Both are described [here](http://prioritized.net/blog/gemify-assets-for-rails/).

1. Making the gem into a `Rails::Engine`
2. Adding the dependency on `railties` into the `gemspec`